# Warning: Unclosed files for the types '[io.realm.OrderListRealmProxy]'; these types will not undergo annotation processing

Tags: java, android, sqlite, annotations, realm

While compiling my Android code, the compiler displayed the following warning:

`warning: Unclosed files for the types '[io.realm.OrderListRealmProxy]'; these types will not undergo annotation processing"`

What is wrong with my Realm object class?

Comment: What is your question? please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 11):

This is because you're using `List<>` instead of `RealmList<>` in an object you've extended RealmObject

Comment: you're a life saver.

Comment: Lol... Happy to help!